# jQuery store scroll position

Tags: jquery, scroll

I've got a couple of click statements like this

```
$('.button1').click(function() {
//grab current scroll position  
    var currentscrollpos = $(window).scrollTop()

    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);

});

$('.button2').click(function() {
    //go back to scroll position
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: currentscrollpos }, 500);

});
```

I'm not sure how to get the current scroll pos and store it in a variable so that I can use it in my other click function

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the variable in the outer scope so that it's available to the other function:

```
var currentscrollpos;

$('.button1').click(function() {
    currentscrollpos = $(window).scrollTop()
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
});

$('.button2').click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: currentscrollpos }, 500);
});
```

You could and should wrap this to a closure to prevent polluting the namespace with unnecessary variables but this should get you started at least.